# Query by contenttype with inheritance

Tags: content-type, caml-query, inheritance

Lets say we have 2 contenttypes:

1. LanguageItem (inherits from item)
2. News (inherits from LanguageItem)

I have a list with contenttype set to "News", including some items.

Is it possible to create a CAML Query, by contenttype, to get all items with contenttype "LanguageItem" (thus also with all "News"-items)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inherited content type IDs starts with parent content type id.
You can use <Contains> condition with CAML and filter on ContentTypeId column pass the value of "LanguageItem" ctype ID.  You can also use BeginsWith

```
<BeginsWith><FieldRef Name="ContentTypeId"/><Value Type="Text">ctypeID</Value></BeginsWith>
```